# Gurobi ILP: Solution starting point after adding a new constraint

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi

I am trying to understand how Gurobi works and have the following question.

Suppose I start with an ILP model 'm' and obtain a solution 'S' using m.optimize(). Now, I add another constraint to the model and re-optimize. Does Gurobi solve the whole problem from scratch or does it use from the found solution 'S' as the starting point and then proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: You mention duality but you say ILP - do you mean LP? MIP?

Comment: @GregGlockner Sorry for the confusion. I did not mean for the word duality to be in the title. New to this site.

Answer (score 1):

Gurobi, as well as every good solver out there, will try to use an available solution as the starting point to the modified problem, if appropriate. What you are asking is referred to as a [warm start](https://www.igi-global.com/dictionary/warm-start/32107).

Specifically, this paragraph from Gurobi's documentation [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/examples/modify_a_model.html) is relevant to your question:

> For linear models, the previously computed solution can be used as an
>   efficient warm start for the modified model. The Gurobi solver retains
>   the previous solution, so the next optimize call automatically starts
>   from the previous solution.

So, yes, it will use thre previous solution S, and will proceed to re-optimize from there, including the new constraint you added.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.I was also trying to find out which method Gurobi uses to solve the problem.

Comment: There is a possibility that a newly added constraint is violated by the previous optimal solution. So, the primal simplex can't be immediately used. There are two options I am aware of, 1) Dual simplex method: It might start with the current optimal yet infeasible solution and move towards feasibility. OR 2) Big M method: It may introduce a surplus variable for the violated constraint and assign a large M as its coefficient in the objective function. But which one does Gurobi use?

Comment: Yes, both options are valid and possible. There are quite a number of tricks that these solvers teams employ. The internal workings of commercial solvers are not usually made available.